# Laravel Mix version() is forgetting one file

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-mix

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and Mix to build my CSS/JS files.

Here is my full webpack.mix.js file :

```
mix
    .webpackConfig({output: {filename: '[name].js', chunkFilename: 'js/[name].[chunkhash].app.js', publicPath: '/'}})
    .js(['resources/assets/js/app.js'], 'public/js')
    .extract(['vue', 'jquery'])
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .version();
```

For some reason, the JS chunks and CSS files are versioned correctly, but my app.js isn't. Obvisouly, this causes various cache-related problems on my webapp.

I tried :

- adding filenames as parameters for version()
- deleting the manifests

But no luck. Any hint would be greatly appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: Can you try removing the `[]` from `mix.js()`?

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, after upgrading Laravel Mix to >1 (1.0.6), the first line isn't needed anymore.
It was previsouly needed to ensure that webpack's code splitting feature would add hashes in chunks names (similar to what mix.version() does) - it was preventing Mix to rename my main app.js file.

By removing this line, everything works as expected.

Comment: My bad, I did not ask for your `Laravel-Mix` version. Yeah, apparently `webpackConfig()` not really needed now.

Comment: Well, apparently, it still is. When I remove the custom config, the chunks aren't "versioned". Looks like it will be really hard to have chunks and main files versioned at the same time...

Comment: Check your `mix-manifest.json` file. There should be hashes in it if you are using `mix.version()`. Hashing on filenames was removed in `v1.0+`